# Adaptation in time versus frequency domain for OFDM systems 5G NR

Tags: ofdm

I hope someone can help me with this. In 5G NR OFDM system, Bandwidth part switching is helpful for power savings. You reduce the transmission bandwidth and then you save on transmit power. That is clear.
So i was thinking why hasnt 3gpp defined adaptation in time domain? Wouldnt that provide gains as well. In this case transmit over the whole bandwidth but for shorter time. Any difference in power savings

Comment: All else being equal, shorter time $\approx$ higher power consumption.

Comment: @AlexTP why Alex? Thank you for your reply

Comment: @Tyrone because you need to keep the same energy for the same error performance.

Comment: In terms of energy consumption is the UE consuming more power transmitting over 10 mhz and 14 symbols compared to 20 mhz and 7 symbols... that is not clear to me

Comment: @Tyrone because power = energy/time and the duration of 7 symbols is shorter than that of 14 symbols. In ideal cases, the energy consumption should be identical but higher power requirement implies more expensive hardware. In pratical cases, (in general) higher power implies more energy loss mainly due to heat conversion. Therefore, low bandwidth is prefered. Note that NR does have short scheduling (mini slots) but only for latency purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OFDM defines the duration of your symbol to be equal to the number of subcarriers. So, that's impossible to change given a bandwidth, unless you've got a different (less frequency-selective) channel. So, OFDM symbol length is fixed.

The number of resource blocks assigned to UE is adjusted according to data volume requirement of the UE, so that kind of time-domain adaptability always has been the case.

Comment: Thank you Marcus. Perhaps my question wasn't clear. And I apologize for that. I meant to say that why not allocate smaller # of OFDM symbols while keeping same bw

Comment: As I wrote, that's exactly what is done when your UE gets a lower number of resource blocks allocated.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Btw the number of resources blocks may have fixed # of symbols. By allocating different # of RBs doesn't necessarily mean fewer symbols

Comment: Ok. Say I allocate 20 mhz and 14 ofdm symbols to UE. Then I decided to allocate 10 mhz and 14 symbols for power saving. Is that same as allocating 20 mhz and 7 symbols in terms of power savings

Comment: Yes, but you can assign fewer "active" symbols to a UE by picking the subset of RBs accordingly.

Comment: @Tyrone I think you mean "does that mean the UE uses the same amount of energy", right? That's impossible to tell. There'd be the same amount of energy in the transmit symbols **assuming identical subcarrier power**, because more subcarriers means proportionally more transmit power, but how that transmit power increase relates to transmit chain power consumption depends on the physics of the analog electronics. However, you'd very rarely do that – your device will usually be told to use the modulation / coding that still achieves the necessary BER, to maximize *cell-wide* SINR!

Comment: which kind of implies that if there's a lot of unused RBs available that your UE could use, then the network will probably prefer if it used a lot of RBs with low power, to achieve the same BER, rather than few with high power. However it really depends. On the other hand, as soon as many users contend for the spectrum at high data rates, it's probably that the network wants UEs to get rid of data in fewer RBs with high bit energy (and thus, larger constellation/more bits per RB), to ease the contention, even at the price of larger MAI. It's a system tradeoff!

Comment: Yes I meant does the UE use the same amount of energy to transmit over 10 mhz and 14 symbols compared to transmitting over 20 mhz and 7 symbols

Comment: as commented above, impossible to tell, since it heavily (orders of magnitude) depends on your transmit chain and in which range relative to the output power range you're operating. Often, avoiding high PAPR by having more OFDM symbols with lower occupancy is advantageous for BER, because you can then increase average symbol power and get out more data in fewer OFDM symbols. It really is a systems design question!